# How to adjust data locales?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I can adjust which data locales I would like to use via Backoffice, but if I change session I should select it again.

So I need to predefine which locales I Would like to use some .properties file.

Which parameter I should use?

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

Backoffice uses *lang.packs* property. In case there is a match between the language your browser uses and one of the languages in the system, the language should be pre-selected.

There is no additional storage, so when you close the browser the previously set language will not be set.